# Create a Json file from another file as a model

Tags: php, json

I'm getting data from DB that will be used as `Values` of my `Keys` on my `file.json`. I already have a "model file", I need to dynamically create another one, with same keys but with different values (fetched from DB).

So basically what I need to do is READ the keys from the existent file and populate the values for these keys with the database data.

```
 //Open model file
 $myFile  = fopen($fileName, "r") or die("Unable to open the file !");
 //$content = file content
 $content = json_decode(fread($myFile, filesize($fileName)));
 fclose($myFile); //Close the file

 foreach( $content as $keys => $value ) {         

    foreach( $value as $key) {
       //....
    }
 }
```

File format is like this:

```
{
    "title1": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
     },
     "title2": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"      
     },
}
```

As you can see I'm able to access all the data I need these loops above.

What I don't know how to do is to write into the file using that file format. (Insert the `title`, `keys`, `values` on the right place).

Comment: As recommended by the staff. Never forget to leave a comment explaining your downvote. Downvote without a comment are not helping anyone in this community. THanks !

Comment: I imagine It was down voted because there is not enough information to answer the question, in other words your asking us to map `x` to `y` without telling us what `x` is or what `y` is.You also haven't provided any code that really attempts to do it, you have just opened the model file and looped though it. FYI, I wasn't the person who downed.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach if I can call it that is deeply flawed.  All you are doing, or all it appears you are doing is looping through data from a file that has JSON data in it.  Perhaps this is the enigmatic `"model file"` but that is not clear. Perhaps it's an example of the format you want.  How should I know.

In any case you don't really give enough information to give a specific answer so I will give a general one.

Assuming you can use PDO and more specifically PDO::FETCH_GROUP, we can take care of the title strait away with that.  Then for the mapping, I would build a mapping array and do something like this (using canned data):

```
$map = [
         'modelKey' =>  'dbKey',
         'modelKey3' =>  'dbKey3',
         'modelKey1' =>  'dbKey1',
         'modelKey2' =>  'dbKey2',
         'modelKey4' =>  'non-dbKey', //not in db
    ];

 $dbResults = [

     'title1' => [
         'dbKey' => 'value',
         'dbKey1' => 'value1',
         'dbKey2' => 'value2',
         'dbKey3' => 'value3',
         'dbKey4' => 'value4', //not in map
    ]
 ];


 $blank = array_fill_keys($map, '');
 $result = [];

 foreach($dbResults as $key => $row){
     //adds any keys in from $blank not in $row
     $mapped = array_replace($blank, $row);
     //removes any keys from row that are not in blank
     $mapped = array_intersect_key($mapped, $blank);
     $result[$key] = $mapped;
 }

 print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array (
    [title1] => Array (
        [dbKey] => value
        [dbKey3] => value3
        [dbKey1] => value1
        [dbKey2] => value2
        [non-dbKey] => 
    )
)
```

Try it online

https://3v4l.org/g4YI1

As you can see, the columns are in the correct order as `map` and the missing one `non-dbKey` is there with an empty value, the extra `dbKey4` is removed.

But you essentially must have a way to tell the program `this_field = that_field`.  Just taking a file with some JSON in it with different keys then a DB array, how can the program know that `this_field = that_field`? Simple, it can't unless you tell it.  There is no magic guess what field I am functions in PHP.